# The Hit Object Within the BlockLogic Superclass is Not Being Called

Tags: python, oop, superclass

When I press the lowercase L key, I want the hit object to be called, reducing the length and width of the squares by 5 each time. It seems that the code within BlockNorm is not referencing the hit object within BlockLogic properly. There is no effect when l is pressed, but no errors either.

I attempted placing print(‘test’), and nothing was printed. If I paste self.blen -=5 and self.bwid -= 5 inside BlockNorm’s def **init**, it has effect. That is why I suspect it is not being connected to the superclass’s hit.

```
win = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 500))

run = True

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
   

    class BlockLogic:

        def __init__(self, blen, bwid, posx, posy):
            self.blen = blen  # the block’s length, width, & position
            self.bwid = bwid
            self.posx = posx
            self.posy = posy

        def hit(self):
            self.blen -= 5  # should reduce length and width by 5 each time l is pressed
            self.bwid -= 5
            if self.blen < 1:
                insertscorestuff = 'hi'
            else:
                placeholder = 'here'


    class BlockNorm(BlockLogic):
        def __init__(self, posx=None, posy=None):
            super().__init__(20, 20, posx, posy)  # features for the normal block type
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (250, 0, 0), (self.posx, self.posy, self.blen, self.bwid))

        def hit(self):
            if keys[pygame.K_l]:  # testing the hit, change later
                print('test')  # test does not print
                super().hit()

    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    BlockNorm(200, 200)
    BlockNorm(500, 250)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the classes `BlockNorm` and `BlockLogic` are properly connected but the `hit` method is not called.

Put the class definitions (`BlockLogic` and `BlockNorm`) outside the run loop, then you can create instances and use their methods. The `print('test')` call is not executed because the method `hit` is never called. It "works" inside `BlockNorm.__init__` because that method is automatically called when you create the instances with `BlockNorm(200, 200)` and `BlockNorm(500, 250)`.

Here is an example how the code could look like:

```
class BlockLogic:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...

    def hit(self):
        ...

class BlockNorm(BlockLogic):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (250, 0, 0), (self.posx, self.posy, self.blen, self.bwid))

# ...

block_norm1 = BlockNorm(200, 200)
block_norm2 = BlockNorm(500, 250)

run = True

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    
    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    if keys[pygame.K_l]:
        block_norm1.hit()
        block_norm2.hit()
    block_norm1.draw(win)
    block_norm2.draw(win)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: I attempted this. First, I either had to move block_norm1 after win.fill or delete win.fill for the block to show. Either way, hit() was still not called.

Comment: I just realized that you draw the `BlockNorm` instances during instance creation in your original code. Since I moved the instance creation out of the loop, calling `hit()` had no visible effect. I updated the code example to handle this issue.